# How could I make grpc server do other work when there is no client calls?

Tags: grpc, nonblocking

I have a simple function that is served with grpc, the starting method of this service is like this:

```
void start_server() {
    string addr("0.0.0.0:50002");
    ImageServiceImpl service;
    ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort(addr, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.RegisterService(&service);
    builder.SetMaxSendMessageSize(1L << 31);
    builder.SetMaxReceiveMessageSize(1L << 31);

    std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "service started, listening to: " << addr << std::endl;

    server->Wait();

}
```

It is a standard grpc server. My problem is that, I need the server to execute other programs when there is no client request called. And when a client request comes, the server program would be 'interrupted' and the server will deal with the request. After dealing with the request, the server continues executing its 'leisure time' program. The problem is that the program would block at the `server->Wait()`, thus when there is not client request comes, the server can do nothing but wait, which is not what I need it to do.

I hope I have expressed myself clearly. How could I do this with grpc ?

Answer (score 0):

Does running a thread before `server->Wait()` not solve this problem?
On .NET C #, I solved it like this:

```
...
// Start other work
MainTask mainTask = new MainTask(configurator, _gRPCManager);
Thread mainThread = new Thread(mainTask.Run);
mainThread.IsBackground = true;
mainThread.Start();
// Start gRPS
CreateHostBuilder(args, configurator).Build().Run();
```